What is the origin of the short future tense of imperfective verbs in Ukrainian (e.g. "читатиму" instead of "буду читати")?
The other Slavic languages I know of require a construction of "<future form of "be"> + verb" (which is also permitted in Ukrainian), so I suspect it is a new evolution and not something that existed in some old common Slavic predecessor and then fell off, but I was wondering how this short form came to be, given that it is formed in a way quite different from the long form.

Wikipedia claims it’s from the infinitive + a personal suffix that originated from ęti ‘take’ (also found in Ukrainian йняти ‘have’). So originally the two forms would semantically be ‘I am [about] to X’ and ‘I take/have to X’. I have no idea if this is true, but it’s typologically plausible.

Note, the two forms are not completely interchangeable, contesting the "instead of" in your question's title. More details here (it was question #1 at Ukrainian.SE): How to choose the proper future form of verbs, e.g. “буду писати” vs. “писатиму”?
